# iOS6 Reading Facebook username ID from Addressbook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6, addressbook

I can read Facebook friends first name, lastname, birthday ... but I am unable to read the Facebook username ID from my address book.

If the Facebook detail is on my phone's addressbook it is reading fine but not if it is from the **CardDAV server**.

If I go to the `AddressBook` on the phone/simulator I can see the usernames... so they are available.

I have `read_stream`, `email`, `read_friendlists`, `publish_stream`, `publish_actions` permissions.

Please help... I have run out of ideas

iOS6, XCode 4.5, Facebook SDK 3.1

```
// Extract
// These all return values

CFStringRef cfsPrefix       = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonPrefixProperty);
CFStringRef cfsFirstname    = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
CFStringRef cfsLastname     = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
CFStringRef cfsCompany      = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
NSDate*     datBirthday     = (NSDate*) CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonBirthdayProperty));
NSDate*     datCreate       = (NSDate*) CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonCreationDateProperty));
NSDate*     datModify       = (NSDate*) CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson, kABPersonModificationDateProperty));

// This never returns a value in strFacebook

NSString *strFacebook;

ABMultiValueRef socialMulti = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef) recPerson, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);

// ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti) always returns 0 ?

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(socialMulti); i++) {
    NSDictionary* social = (__bridge NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(socialMulti, i);

    if ([social[@"service"] isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString*)kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook]) {
        strFacebook = (NSString*)social[@"username"];
        NSLog(@"we got a facebook. username is %@ %@", [self nameForSource:(__bridge ABRecordRef)recPerson], cFacebook);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the following and it works.
I know this is not exactly what you are doing but still - my `ABMultiValueGetCount` works fine.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

NSMutableArray *socialArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ABMultiValueRef socialProfiles = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(socialProfiles); i++) {
    NSDictionary *socialItem = (__bridge NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(socialProfiles, i);
    [socialArray addObject:socialItem];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the facebook IM and add this name to www.facebook.com/(fbName)

```
 ABMultiValueRef profile = ABRecordCopyValue(who,  kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(profile) > 0)
{
    // collect all emails in array

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(profile); i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *socialItem = (__bridge NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(profile, i);
        NSString* SocialLabel =  [socialItem objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey];

         if([SocialLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonInstantMessageServiceFacebook])
        {

            NSString *facebookProfile = ([socialItem objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey]);
            NSLog(@"fbName %@",facebookProfile);
        }

    }
    CFRelease(profile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns an empty NSString ("") if there is no Facebook alias for the contact.

```
- (NSString*)facebookAliasForContact:(ABRecordRef)person {
    ABMultiValueRef instantMessage = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
    NSString *facebookAlias = @"";

    if (instantMessage) {
        for (NSInteger i=0 ; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(instantMessage); i++) {
            CFDictionaryRef instantMessageValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(instantMessage, i);
            CFStringRef instantMessageString = CFDictionaryGetValue(instantMessageValue, kABPersonSocialProfileUsernameKey);

    if (CFStringCompare(instantMessageString, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceFacebook, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            facebookAlias = (__bridge NSString *)instantMessageString;
        }        

    CFRelease(instantMessageString);
            CFRelease(instantMessageValue);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(instantMessage);

    return facebookAlias;
}
```